# Query an MS Access geodatabase for specific field shape data in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access

I'm trying to help my wife with something in ArcMap.  She works with ArcMap/ArcGIS every day but has no programming or database knowledge beyond creating basic tables, queries and forms in Access.  I, on the other hand, have good knowledge of programming and databases, but none with ArcMap (so I apologize in advance if my terminology is misleading or flat out wrong).

We have an Access database which is basically a manure spreading log and we're trying to create a report that will pull a particular days spreading activity (ie, which fields were spread, acres, how much was spread, etc.).  Along with that, she'd like to generate/pull the shapefile data for only those fields so that when working in ArcMap she doesn't have to pull in the shape data for every single field (there are a LOT).

We've successfully exported the shapefile data into an Access database, but we're stuck at being able to query it and get the query to work within ArcMap.  What I mean by that is, the data we exported shows up in the catalog in ArcMap and the "table" can be dragged over to the map layers to draw the shape data for all the fields.  We're trying to create a query we can drag over to draw only the fields she's currently working with.  Is there any way to do this?